# Running the benchmarks - new to .NET

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-code, benchmarking, mimekit

I'm attempting to run the benckmarks in https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit and running into version issue. I'm on a mac, using vscode and installed .NET SDK with homebrew. It gave me dotnet-sdk-5.0.401-osx-x64.pkg. When I try to run `dotnet build` in the Benchmarks directory I'm getting

```sh
% dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  MimeKit -> /Users/chris.topinka/smarsh-vscode-dev/MimeKit/MimeKit/bin/Debug/net50/MimeKit.dll
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/Users/chris.topinka/smarsh-vscode-dev/MimeKit/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/Users/chris.topinka/smarsh-vscode-dev/MimeKit/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.84
```

Is there a way to get the right version installed or re-target the project to 5? Thanks.

Comment: I'm over in https://gitter.im/jstedfast/MimeKit now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with building the MimeKit project itself which is multi-targeted (including .NET v4.5).

Apparently you don't have the necessary SDKs installed for .NETFramework v4.5, so it fails to build.

You can disable this by editing the MimeKit.csproj and editing the `<TargetFrameworks>` value to remove `net45`.

In other words, the current value is:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net45;net46;net47;net48;net50</TargetFrameworks>
```

What you need to edit to be is:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net46;net47;net48;net50</TargetFrameworks>
```

Update:

I saw your questions over on gitter.

Since you are attempting to benchmark MimeKit's parser and compare it to Mime4j, it might be easier to just use https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeParserBenchmark instead (same idea, this is just split out from the MimeKit codebase).

That will use the MimeKit nuget packages which will be easier and allow you to target .net5 or .net48 or any other .net framework version you want by editing the Benchmark.csproj file and changing the `<TargetFramework>` XML node to `net50` or whatever.

It also compares the mime4net package which is a port of mime4j
The existing benchmarks measure the time it takes to parse a message (or mbox) 100's or 1000's of times.